# Generating CityGML file with number of storey attribute values from shp file?

Tags: fme-form, fields-attributes, citygml

I am trying to convert shp file to cityGML. In shapefile I have building footprints with attributes "storey" as number of storeys. I want to match this attribute to number of storeys attributes of cityGML buildings class.

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with CityGML files before, but a quick search of the [**help documentation**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/citygml/citygml.htm) indicated that the features for CityGML are stored in the folder:

```
xml/CityGML/writer_feature_types/
```

This is a subfolder of your installation folder.

Locate the file: `CityGML_feature_types.xml` which will be the file which you will import feature types from.

In FME, add a CityGML writer.  Depending on how you have your writer set up, you can either import the feature types after the writer has been added, or add them when you Add the writer.  For me, I imported the feature type definitions when I added the writer:

[image]

Pressing OK will open another dialog.  Navigate to the file `CityGML_feature_types.xml` and press OK.  Select the feature types you need.  I'm just selecting Building here:
[image]

You can see that all of the attributes for buildings have been imported. It looks like there are a few attributes for storeys.  However, citygml_storeys_above_ground looks to be the relevant attribute.

[image]

There are several ways to map attributes in FME, probably the simplest one is to draw a line from the attribute in my reader to the attribute in my writer as so:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this is exactly the solution. Thanks for that helpful answer